# Separating non structured sentences from text corpus

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, nltk

I'm working on a project where I have to separate proper sentences from the text corpus. I have tried with NLTK sentence tokenizer but it seems to tokenize sentences based on periods(".").

So I was thinking is there any way to separate tabular data, phrases from the text file?

Here is a sample text file. I'm referring those under the TEXT tag.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <TEXT><![CDATA[


Record date: 2078-09-07





RYBURY HOSPITAL INTERN ADMISSION NOTE





Name: Goldberg, Joel

MR #: 0370149 

Date of admission: 9/6/2078

Resident: Lange/Bailey

Attending: Schmidt MD

PCP: Odom, Kacie MD



CC:    L foot pain   



HPI: The patient is a 48 yo gentleman with a hx of DM2, peripheral neuropathy and PVD with multiple admissions for LE cellulitis in the setting of gangrenous toes in the past 5 years, last one in July. He now presents with acute on chronic LLE sweeling that began this morning after he got up walked around his home for about 2-3 hrs and then suddenly felt an acute pain shooting up his leg, with a severity of 10/10, he knew right away this was similar to the pain he had felt before on prior admissions for cellulitis so he called 911. On arrival to the ED his temp was 98.1, 112, 145/79, 20, 99%RA and was started on antibiotic treatment with Unasyn for cellulitis.      



ROS:  Per HPI. No F/C/NS.  No CP/Palps.  No Orthopnea. No SOB/cough/hemoptysis/wheezing/sore throat/.  No hematochezia/melena. No delta MS/LOC. No slurring of speech, unilateral weakness. No dysuria.  No chills or fevers, no lightheadedness.



PMH:   

1.  DM2 diagnosed in 2075, says peripheral neuropathy was diagnosed around the same time, denies any retinopathy or nephropathy.

2.  Peripheral vascular disease with the following surgeries performed:

  Right 5th toe amputation 2/2 osteomyelitis 12/14/76

Right 4th toe amputation 2/2 wet gangrene 9/03/76

Angioplasty and stenting of the distal LEFT superficial femoral artery 11/6/76

Angioplasty and stenting of the distal RIGHT superficial femoral artery 7/20/76

I&D of right thigh abscess 4/75



Medications on admission (confirmed with patient):

1.  Glyburide 2.5mg BID

2.  Glucopahge 500mg QD

3.  Zestril 2.5mg QD

4.  Percocet PRN



ALL:  Codeine upsets his stomach

SH: Lives in Arroyo Grande apartment with friend, works occasionally as a copy editor but unemployed right now, has smoked 1/2ppd for 35 years, no ETOH, no drugs. Adequate diet.

FH: Many family members with DM.    



Physical Exam:  

V:  98.5, 149/84, 98, 18, 99%RA

Gen:  NAD, conversant

HEENT: PERRL, EOMI.    

Neck:  Supple, no thyromegaly, no carotid bruits, JVP 

Nodes: No cervical or supraclavicular LAN

Cor: RRR S1, S2 nl.  No m/r/g.  No S3, S4

Chest: CTAB  

Abdomen: +BS Soft, NT, ND.  No HSM, No CVA tenderness. 

Ext: LLE with dorsal and medial erythema, extending from L 5th toe that has eschar on its side and is mildly tender, no secretions. L toe also tender. Pulse on LLE + and RLE ++.

Skin: No other rashes

Neuro: AO X 3. CN II-XII intact. Decreased sensation from LT up to knee on R and 4cm above ankle on Left..



Labs and Studies:

  RSC       

            09/06/78  

            10:17     



NA          137                                                       

K           4.5(T)                                                    

CL          106                                                       

CO2         28.4                                                      

BUN         25                                                        

CRE         0.9                                                       

GLU         266(H)                                                    

CA          9.5                                                       

PHOS        3.1                                                       

MG          1.7                                                       



CBC

WBC         12.7(H)                                                   

RBC         4.13(L)                                                   

HGB         13.0(L)                                                   

HCT         37.1(L)                                                   

MCV         90                                                        

MCH         31.5                                                      

MCHC        35.0                                                      

PLT         165                                                       

RDW         13.3                                                      

DIFFR       Received                                                  

METHOD      Auto                                                      

%NEUT       79(H)                                                     

%LYMPH      17(L)                                                     

%MONO       3(L)                                                      

%EOS        1                                                         

%BASO       0                                                         

ANEUT       10.02(H)                                                  

ALYMP       2.13                                                      

AMONS       0.44(H)                                                   

AEOSN       0.11                                                      

ABASOP      0.03                                                      

ANISO       None                                                      

HYPO        None                                                      

MACRO       None                                                      

MICRO       None                                                      



PT          11.9                                                      

PTT         25.0                                                      



LENIS: Negative for DVT, did not assess arteries.

FOOT ANKLE XR: There is a lytic lesion in the distal lateral aspect of the proximal phalanx of the fifth toe. This can be consitent with an area of infection/osteomyelitis.



Microbiology 

21-Jul-2076 09:41  

  Specimen Type:     WOUND

  Specimen Comment: ULCER  4TH 5TH TOE



  Wound Culture - Final    Reported: 24-Jul-76 15:05

    Moderate PROTEUS VULGARIS

      RAPID METHOD

      Antibiotic                      Interpretation

      ----------------------------------------------

      Amikacin                        Susceptible   

      Ampicillin                      Resistant     

      Aztreonam                       Susceptible   

      Cefazolin                       Resistant     

      Cefepime                        Susceptible   

      Cefpodoxime                     Susceptible   

      Ceftriaxone                     Susceptible   

      Gentamicin                      Susceptible   

      Levofloxacin                    Susceptible   

      Piperacillin                    Susceptible   

      Trimethoprim/Sulfamethoxazole   Susceptible   







A/P: 48M with a hx of DM2, PVD and multiple admissions in the past for LE cellulitis in the setting of gangrene. 

1.  ID: Patient is now presenting with appears to be another episode of cellulitis but now probably coming from his L 5th Toe lesion. Surgery has debrided the wound, sending wound cultures as well as blood cultures. Acute OM would not be visible on XR changes and clinical picture is more consistent with acute than Chronic OM. Will consider further work up for OM if symptoms do not respond to treatment. Levo and flagyl were added to unasyn in accord to previous culture data.

2.  PVD: Will need arterial LENIS to assess for vascular patency and flow. Continuing ACEI, and adding ASA and lipitor, will order lipid profile and smoking cessation consult.

3.  DM2: Very poor control last admission, eventhough patient now says he takes medications and checks it up to QID. Will order HgbA1C and glucose monitoring.



_______________________________________________________________________

Name Ian Jurado MD                               

Pager # 14558

PGY-1











]]></TEXT>
  <TAGS>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC0" time="during DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M0" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="during DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M1" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="during DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M2" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="during DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC1" time="after DCT" type1="statin" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M3" start="7111" end="7133" text="adding ASA and lipitor" time="after DCT" type1="statin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M4" start="7126" end="7133" text="lipitor" time="after DCT" type1="statin" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <DIABETES id="DOC2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention">
      <DIABETES id="D0" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D1" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D2" start="1180" end="1183" text="DM2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D3" start="6444" end="6447" text="DM2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D4" start="7195" end="7198" text="DM2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D5" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="before DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
    </DIABETES>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC3" time="after DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M5" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="after DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M6" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="after DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M7" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="after DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC4" time="after DCT" type1="metformin" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M8" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="after DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M9" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="after DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M10" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="after DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC5" time="during DCT" type1="metformin" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M11" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="during DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M12" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="during DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M13" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="during DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <HYPERTENSION id="DOC6" time="during DCT" indicator="high bp">
      <HYPERTENSION id="H0" start="2100" end="2106" text="149/84" time="during DCT" indicator="high bp" comment=""/>
      <HYPERTENSION id="H1" start="828" end="834" text="145/79" time="during DCT" indicator="high bp" comment=""/>
    </HYPERTENSION>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC7" time="before DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M14" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="before DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M15" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="before DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M16" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="before DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <SMOKER id="DOC8" status="current">
      <SMOKER id="S0" start="7163" end="7191" text=" smoking cessation consult. " status="current" comment=""/>
      <SMOKER id="S1" start="1965" end="1995" text="has smoked 1/2ppd for 35 years" status="current" comment=""/>
      <SMOKER id="S2" start="1969" end="1995" text="smoked 1/2ppd for 35 years" status="current" comment=""/>
    </SMOKER>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC9" time="before DCT" type1="metformin" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M17" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="before DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M18" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="before DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M19" start="1758" end="1768" text="Glucopahge" time="before DCT" type1="metformin" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC10" time="after DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M20" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="after DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M21" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="after DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M22" start="1782" end="1789" text="Zestril" time="after DCT" type1="ACE inhibitor" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC11" time="during DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M23" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="during DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M24" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="during DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M25" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="during DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <DIABETES id="DOC12" time="during DCT" indicator="mention">
      <DIABETES id="D6" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="during DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D7" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="during DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D8" start="1180" end="1183" text="DM2" time="during DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D9" start="6444" end="6447" text="DM2" time="during DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D10" start="7195" end="7198" text="DM2" time="during DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D11" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="during DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
    </DIABETES>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC13" time="after DCT" type1="aspirin" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M26" start="7111" end="7133" text="adding ASA and lipitor" time="after DCT" type1="aspirin" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M27" start="7118" end="7121" text="ASA" time="after DCT" type1="aspirin" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <FAMILY_HIST id="DOC14" indicator="not present">
      <FAMILY_HIST id="F0" indicator="not present"/>
      <FAMILY_HIST id="F1" indicator="not present"/>
      <FAMILY_HIST id="F2" indicator="not present"/>
    </FAMILY_HIST>
    <DIABETES id="DOC15" time="after DCT" indicator="mention">
      <DIABETES id="D12" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="after DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D13" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="after DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D14" start="1180" end="1183" text="DM2" time="after DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D15" start="6444" end="6447" text="DM2" time="after DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D16" start="7195" end="7198" text="DM2" time="after DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
      <DIABETES id="D17" start="296" end="299" text="DM2" time="after DCT" indicator="mention" comment=""/>
    </DIABETES>
    <MEDICATION id="DOC16" time="before DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="">
      <MEDICATION id="M28" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="before DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M29" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="before DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
      <MEDICATION id="M30" start="1734" end="1743" text="Glyburide" time="before DCT" type1="sulfonylureas" type2="" comment=""/>
    </MEDICATION>
    <PHI id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2078-09-07" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P1" start="39" end="54" text="RYBURY HOSPITAL" TYPE="HOSPITAL"/>
    <PHI id="P2" start="88" end="102" text="Goldberg, Joel" TYPE="PATIENT"/>
    <PHI id="P3" start="110" end="117" text="0370149" TYPE="MEDICALRECORD"/>
    <PHI id="P4" start="139" end="147" text="9/6/2078" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P5" start="159" end="164" text="Lange" TYPE="DOCTOR"/>
    <PHI id="P6" start="165" end="171" text="Bailey" TYPE="DOCTOR"/>
    <PHI id="P7" start="184" end="191" text="Schmidt" TYPE="DOCTOR"/>
    <PHI id="P8" start="201" end="212" text="Odom, Kacie" TYPE="DOCTOR"/>
    <PHI id="P9" start="267" end="269" text="48" TYPE="AGE"/>
    <PHI id="P10" start="441" end="445" text="July" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P11" start="1197" end="1201" text="2075" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P12" start="1422" end="1430" text="12/14/76" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P13" start="1474" end="1481" text="9/03/76" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P14" start="1554" end="1561" text="11/6/76" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P15" start="1635" end="1642" text="7/20/76" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P16" start="1671" end="1675" text="4/75" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P17" start="1866" end="1879" text="Arroyo Grande" TYPE="CITY"/>
    <PHI id="P18" start="1927" end="1938" text="copy editor" TYPE="PROFESSION"/>
    <PHI id="P19" start="2717" end="2720" text="RSC" TYPE="HOSPITAL"/>
    <PHI id="P20" start="2740" end="2748" text="09/06/78" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P21" start="5510" end="5521" text="21-Jul-2076" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P22" start="5638" end="5647" text="24-Jul-76" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <PHI id="P23" start="6427" end="6429" text="48" TYPE="AGE"/>
    <PHI id="P24" start="7431" end="7441" text="Ian Jurado" TYPE="DOCTOR"/>
    <PHI id="P25" start="7485" end="7490" text="14558" TYPE="PHONE"/>
  </TAGS>
</root>
```

Whenever I try to tokenize the text above on sentence basis, NLTK messes up and kind of lumps all phrases it can find before a period (".") as a sentence.

Comment: I think for this particular case you're better off writing a simple sentence splitter yourself. One that splits on two newlines seems to do the trick here. After that, you can see if feeding the resulting elements of that list to the nltk sentence segmenter improves output quality or not.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, but I also happen to have some files where newlines are at inappropriate places like somewhere inside a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Some lines (really paragraphs) in this file contain multiple sentences. Break up the file into lines, then apply the sentence tokenizer to each line separately. This will prevent merging text from different lines, and will give you much better results than rolling your own regexp-based sentence splitter. For example:

```
text = file.read()
lines = text.splitlines()
sentences = [ s for line in lines for s in nltk.sent_tokenize(line) ]
```

Comment: What is lines.text.splitlines() here? Just a sample format of the kind of method/class I might use?

Comment: Oops, typo! Sorry about that :-( No, this is complete working code provided you have opened the file for reading.